# Book about an alien race conquering Earth and conducting experiments on humans to revert them to animal-like beasts

Tags: story-identification, novel, alien-invasion

Cannot remember a book read in school, the theme being about an alien race conquering Earth and conducting experiments on humans to revert them to animal-like beasts.

The aliens carry a lance or a trident-shaped weapon with a button or trigger at the rear end. The front end glows red before firing. One of the beast/human hybrids is not as feral as his kindred and speaks, and may have simple reading skills.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to add these details?

Comment: Not the answer to the question, but _The Golden Helix_ by Theodore Sturgeon might be of interest related to the devolution theme.

Comment: Hmmm. Some similarities to Stableford's Dies Irae series of books - Days of Glory, in the Kingdom of the Beasts, etc. Only I'm pretty sure it was reversed and the humans created the beast people.